# How to add mouselisteners outside the constructor

Tags: java, jbutton, mouselistener

In the example below, both button and button2 are supposed to become unclickable when you press them. When you press the reset button, the two disabled buttons are supposed to work again.

Since I made the two buttons unclickable by removing their mouseListeners, how do add the mouseListeners back using the check() method so they still function in the same way again?

```
public static boolean isreset = false;
public static JButton button = new JButton("Disable button 1");
public static JButton button2 = new JButton("Disable button 2");
public static JButton reset = new JButton("Reset all buttons");

Test() {
    setTitle("Button Test");
    setSize(420, 80);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gc.gridheight = 1;
    gc.gridwidth = 1;

    gc.gridx = 0;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    buttons.add(button, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    buttons.add(button2, gc);

    gc.gridx = 3;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    buttons.add(reset, gc);

    add(buttons);

    button.addMouseListener(new Mouse(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            button.setEnabled(false);
            button.removeMouseListener(this);
            System.out.println("You pressed button 1.");
            isreset = false;
            check(isreset);
        }
    });

    button2.addMouseListener(new Mouse(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button2.removeMouseListener(this);
            System.out.println("You pressed button 2.");
            isreset = false;
            check(isreset);
        }
    });

    reset.addMouseListener(new Mouse(){
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            isreset = true;
            check(isreset);
        }
    });

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void check (boolean input){
    if(input == true){
        Test.button.setEnabled(true);
        Test.button.addMouseListener(this); //error here
        Test.button2.setEnabled(true);
        Test.button2.addMouseListener(this); //error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why removing the mouseListener at all ??

Comment: And why is everything `static`? That's your real problem - in a static method, there is no `this`.

Comment: You cant store the mouseListener objects and add them again, but why removing mouseListener ?

Comment: Are you implementing `MouseListener`? When you call `Test.button.addMouseListener(this);`, you are saying that this is an implementation of `MouseListener` and to add it to the button. Although I would just not remove it at all and switch the enabled flag.

Comment: `addMouseListener(this)` means the class you are writing the code in is a `MouseListener` or extends one,  but it is NOT, you are passing MouseListener as an anonymous inner class, you need to make an object of the MouseListeners and use them when you add/remove listener

Comment: in other words, `this` used in `mousePressed()` is different than `this` used in `check()` because the first points to the MouseListener instance and the second points to the class your code exists in

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your code is `static`. That's not how you write a `JFrame` subclass. I suggest you to read some sample code first.

You don't have to remove the mouse listeners each time. Just calling `setEnabled` is enough.

Also, you should call `addActionListener` instead of `addMouseListener`.

Example:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        button.setEnabled(false);
        System.out.println("You pressed button 1.");
        isreset = false;
        check(isreset);
    }
});
```